# NSInvalidArgumentException [__NSCFNumber length] in ruby motion tableview

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I'm getting this error "unrecognised selector sent to instance.." I think the problem is this code here. Whether I give it a to_s or to_i, it throws the same error. If I set it to 0 the error isn't thrown but no data shows in table. Any ideas for what this might be?

The method that throws the error

```
 def tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)     


 end
```

The different ways I've tried to return from this method

```
@data.count.to_s # (throws this error)                                                                                                                         

@data.count.to_s # (throws this error)                                                                                                                          

0 # (no error thrown, but no data in table)
```

The error as thrown by ruby motion

> 2014-07-14 23:54:30.416 apeact[51846:80b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfe618f0'

Comment: What are those empty regex or hyphens followed by an invalid expression?

Comment: Your title looks like Objective-C rather than Ruby.

Comment: @sawa This is the error thrown by RubyMotion at runtime (after it has compiled to ObjectiveC from Ruby)? I edited the question to make less ambiguous

Comment: It sounds like @data is something other than what you expect it to be. `count` is an alias for `length` in some objects.